# What could be causing a runtime error in my C++ implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm?

Tags: c++

WHY RUN TIME ERROR?..please help
i am trying to output the ith prime number but i keep gettng run time error.i can run the code in an offline compiler but  not in a online compiler

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<long long>prima;
long long int SieveOfEratosthenes(){
    bool prime[1000006];
    for (long long int p = 2; p <= 1000000; p++) {
        if (prime[p]==false){
        prima.push_back(p);
            for (long long int i = p * p; i <= 1000000; i += p){
                prime[i] = true;
            }                
        }   
    }
}     

int main(){ 
    long t;
    cin>>t;
    SieveOfEratosthenes();
    while(t--){
        long long int k;
        cin>>k;
        cout<<prima[k-1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `bool prime[1000006];` this is too large array for a relative small stack. Reduce the array.

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from? `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` is an indication its not a good source. You also should return something from your sieve function and use a debugger to find some bugs in your logic too. Replace your "array" with std::vector<bool>, since your array is too big to fit on the stack.

Comment: I dunno, but your `SieveOfEratosthenes` doest' actually return a value. Hence, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please confirm that a) the code you are using and which exhibits the problem you describe is the code shown here, i.e. a [mre] b) it can be compiled and run c) it has a runtime error, i.e. an error occurring while running it d) not a TLE ("time limit exceeded"), i.e. a failure to satisfy an online-judge, because of taking too long e) you wrote the code

Comment: [C/C++ the result of the uninitialized array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351746/c-c-the-result-of-the-uninitialized-array) and [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
bool prime[1000006];
```

Leaves the values in `prime` undefined including trap values that will cause undefined behavior.  Even if you fix that, it risks stack overflow for being so large.

So just replace the above line with:

```
std::vector<bool> prime(1000006);
```

Aside from a `#include <vector>` at the top of the file, everything else remains the same.

Comment: You haven't addressed the fact that a function declared as returning a `long long int` doesn't actually return *anything*.

Comment: @AdrianMole I called that out in the comments below the OP's question. Seeing how the code wouldn't (likely) compile unless this was addressed...